# 'Scale to fit below the built-in camera' option not avaliable on M2 Macbook Air

Tags: macos

I cannot find the ['Scale to fit below the built-in camera'](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212842) option on my M2 Air on MacOS 12.4.

[image]

Any other options?

Answer (score 2):

FaceTime can't do Full Screen, nor change its window size to fill the screen.

The checkbox is an option for some apps; not for all. The Apple Support page you link to says:

> Apps can be updated to work better with this area of your screen. If a
> developer updates their app for compatibility with your Mac, the
> "Scale to fit below built-in camera" setting no longer appears.

A quick check shows that none of the OS-bundled apps have the option, but Logic, Pages, Numbers and Keynote do.

Comment: That can't be right: I don't see the option for Safari, which can be displayed in full screen, but I can see it for Blackmagic Disk Speed Test,, which doesn't display in full screen at all.  Mainly I find this option for 3ʳᵈ party applications, not built-in ones. Which applications did you check?

Comment: I suspect it's an option that apps have to support, or not.

Comment: It certainly looks that way.  It would also explain why many of the built-in apps don't show it.  From mic's link: "If a developer updates their app for compatibility with your Mac, the "Scale to fit below built-in camera" setting no longer appears."

Comment: @mic Does FaceTime pose a problem at all?  Maybe you could post a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: It's not just facetime. It's the same on Stardew Valley which I know for a fact has this support. I just took Facetime as a random example